# URL Rewrite failing

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track-search?artist=TINA-TURNER&action=search&listArtist=true
```

Which I want to read:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track-search/TINA-TURNER
```

This is what I'm trying but it simply takes me to `http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track-search` without any of the `GET` variables

```
RewriteRule ^(tracks)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2?artist=$3&action=$4&listArtist=$5 [QSA,L]
```

Is this possible or do I have to include the `action` and `listArtist` variables in the URL too? (I could probably flag them if they're not there in PHP file but thats easy)

I also tried, which fails:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track-search/TINA-TURNER/search/true
```

**EDIT** I think there may be some confusion, my fault...

In the original URL

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track-search?artist=TINA-TURNER&action=search&listArtist=true
```

Notice

```
...backing-track-search?artist...
```

Well `backing-track-search` is actually a file, `backing-track-search.html` not a directory - i simply left off the .html as I have that rule written in the `.htaccess` file

Comment: Going to `/tracks/backing-track-search/TINA-TURNER/search/true` works for me when I put that rule in my htaccess file

Comment: Is `tracks/backing-track-search/` always in the URL?

Comment: @JonLin - it doesn't pull the variables using $_GET[]

Comment: @Pjack Yeah, but can do away with /tracks/ if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you did this in .htaccess?

```
RewriteRule ^backing-track-search/([^/]+) /tracks/backing-track-search.html?artist=$1&action=search&listArtist=true&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Then use

```
http://mysite.com/backing-track-search/TINA-TURNER
```

Comment: Thanks again, Same problem, doesn't pick up the variables - e.g. try echo $_GET['action'] and it does nothing, tried also with [QSA,L] at the end

Comment: Is URL rewriting turned on? Updated answer to make sure its on.

Comment: Does your .htaccess file control anything else? Meaning is it allowed in the apache config file? Just making sure htaccess is actually doing something.

Comment: I have other rewrite rules in there and some other stuff so yeah, it definitely works ok - I even tried commenting out the other rule to see if there was a conflict but there isn't

Comment: Is there an index.php file in `backing-track-search`? Is that a real folder?

Comment: Updated my answer if thats a folder. That above works for me.

Comment: Have updated question, there's some confusion which is hopefuly now cleared up.

Comment: ok what if you removed tracks and did it this way since you said you really don't need tracks anyway. Does this work for you?  updated the answer.

Comment: Outstanding! I'm learning a lot about this now and can really start to use them to good effect - thanks so much, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see all 3 variables in `$_GET` when I create a php script in `/tracks/backing-track-search`, using your 2nd rule in a blank htaccess file in my document root.

What may be going on here is that simply going to `/tracks/backing-track-search/something-something` is running the script right off the bat so nothing is getting rewritten (especially if you're using conditions like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` or `!-d`). Then the PATH INFO for the script ends up with a `/something-something` in it. You *could* try renaming the URL to something different, like:

```
http://mysite.com/tracks/backing-track/TINA-TURNER/search/true
```

Then your rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^tracks/backing-track/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /tracks/backing-track-search?artist=$1&action=$2&listArtist=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have updated question, there's some confusion which is hopefuly now cleared up.